# How/where to ask about recommended practices, websites, etc. in freelancing?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I wanted to ask a question about freelancing, recommended practices, web sites, etc., but I see lot of such questions are closed as off-topic.

Where or how should I ask such question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Se an example of a [popular question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23691/why-are-more-programmers-not-freelance-these-days) related to freelancing.

(BTW I'm assuming you mean programming realated - if not, maybe on [OnStartups](http://answers.onstartups.com/)?)

Comment: I think OnStartups will fit my question, thanks!

Comment: No problem! glad to help!