# Stack Exchange Site for Deciding Where to Post Questions

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, site-proposal

Is there a Stack Exchange site where users post their questions not to get answers or to get up voted or down voted for quality, but to decide on which site to post their questions? If not, does anybody else think that a site like this should be created? Up votes and down votes could be allotted for how obvious the correct site to post to is. For example, a question that obviously asks about why their code is broken would be sent to SO possibly with down votes. However, a question that spans both programming and academia where it is unclear which subject is dominant, could get up votes for its complexity and deserving to be asked.

Is helping to decide where questions go a function of Meta Stack Exchange or should another site be created?

Are there any negatives to creating a site like this?

Comment: You found it, it's this one.

Comment: Feel free to propose such a site [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Review a few of the questions here using the [tag:site-recommendation] tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the simplest way to figure which Stack Exchange site to post on is to perform a Google Search using the title of your question or some keywords from it.

Inevitably, near the top of the results should be some Stack Exchange sites, and probably only one or a few of them.

Visit the help/on-topic page(s) for that/those sites to see if it or one of them sounds like a place where your question is on-topic, and assuming that it does, then post it.

The worst that can happen is that your question gets Closed as being off-topic, and in the process you will have started to learn about that site's scope and/or about the type of editing necessary to bring it on-topic there.

I see no need for a site to "test post" questions.

Answer (score 3):

> Is helping to decide where questions go a function of Meta Stack Exchange or should another site be created?

That would most likely be this one's job.

If you've ever taken a look around the list of questions here, you may have seen a couple of questions asking where to post something. From my understanding, these are on-topic here.

*Examples:*

- [Where to ask questions about computer settings?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201648/where-to-ask-questions-about-computer-settings?s=5%7C1.7210)
- [Where to ask this question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89765/where-to-ask-this-question?s=6%7C1.7021)
- [freelancing - how / where to ask?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75493/freelancing-how-where-to-ask?s=4%7C1.7529)

Comment: Or, just browse the [tag:site-recommendation] tag.

Answer (score -1):

If you have no idea at all of where to post, then post a question here on Meta Stack Exchange asking about it using the [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag. People can offer suggestions to places you might not even know existed.

If you think that your question might pertain to a couple different sites and then you might be able to post on the meta of each site asking if it's on-topic. This requires that you have 5 rep on the site, so you'll either need to have gained that already or be eligible for the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus).

The added advantage to this approach is that some questions are on-topic in multiple places, and you may be told it's acceptable to post in more than one. Also you will have evidence that you were told the question is on-topic, if other people respond saying it's an off-topic post.