# Is there a Stack Exchange site for material science topics?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site for material science topics?

Answer (score 7):

I tried [googling "material science stack"](https://www.google.com/search?q=material%20science%20stack) and [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/material-science) floated to the top so that looks to be one home for questions on Material Science.  This is the approach that I advocated for finding which site to post any question on in an [earlier answer to another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263952/215590).

There do not seem to be any proposals for a Material Science site at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

The other sites you mentioned do not seem to have any questions tagged `material-science`.

@NormalHuman has suggested that:

> Additionally, some of the more applied questions about materials could
>   be on [Engineering](http://engineering.stackexchange.com).

where you could look for [questions tagged `materials`](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/materials).

Comment: Additionally, some of the more applied questions about materials could be on [Engineering](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/materials).

Comment: For my future reference, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317248/stress-strain-behaviour-of-al2o3-at-different-temperatures  I'm posting a link to a Q that will be deleted soon, but I want to preserve its url address. I'm thinking of writing up a meta post...

Answer (score 5):

There is now a [Materials Stack Exchange](https://materials.stackexchange.com/) which moved from Private Beta to Public today :)

You can also see the [original proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling) for it on Area51.

There's a lot of very dedicated users there (70 "avid users", meaning users with 200+ rep, in the 3 weeks of Private Beta).

I hope the site can be useful to y'all!

Comment: More precisely, a materials modeling site. What is the policy with regards to non-modeling questions?

Comment: @JonCuster There's been some well-received (20+ upvotes) questions that were about materials but not about the modeling of them: https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/329/what-has-caused-this-apparent-stagnancy-in-the-development-of-more-efficient-so. There was also some questions about perovskites that wasn't specifically about the modeling of them. These questions were asked right from the beginning in the Area51 Definition period, so it was understood early on that the Materials Modeling community would also be interested in some pure materials science too.